# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module with LABJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, labjs

I keep getting this error when loading my Angular app. In Chrome a couple refreshes and my app will run but IE and FF is a no go.

The error links me to this [error page](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/%24injector%3amodulerr?p0=spApp&p1=Error%3a%20%5B%24injector%3anomod%5D%20http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.4/%24injector/nomod?p0=spApp%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20%28na) but I don't really understand what it says.

I am loading my app using [LabsJS](http://labjs.com/) including the controllers and service.

```
// spAppLoader.js

$LAB
    .script("../js/app.js").wait()
    .script("../js/controllers/userCtrl.js")
    .script("../js/controllers/groupCtrl.js")
    .script("../js/controllers/siteCtrl.js")
    .script("../js/services/userServices.js")
    .script("../js/services/groupServices.js")
    .script("../js/services/siteServices.js")
```

Markup:

```
<div id="mdContainer" ng-app="spApp" ng-cloak>
  ...
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/spAppLoader.js"></script>
```

I wanted to post more code but I don't know where to start and with angular everything is in multiple files. I uploaded it through [github](https://github.com/simkessy/spDash/).

Comment: plnkr.co is great for Angular issues

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should [manually bootstrap](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap) your app because you use an asynchronous script loader:

```
$LAB
    .script("../js/app.js").wait()
    .script("../js/controllers/userCtrl.js")
    .script("../js/controllers/groupCtrl.js")
    .script("../js/controllers/siteCtrl.js")
    .script("../js/services/userServices.js")
    .script("../js/services/groupServices.js")
    .script("../js/services/siteServices.js")
    .wait(function(){
      var root = document.getElementById('mdContainer')
      angular.bootstrap(root ,['spApp']);
    })
```

#### What is bootstrapping?

`angular.bootstrap(root ,['spApp']);` is the same as `<div id="mdContainer" ng-app="spApp">` only the last one would automatically initialize your app when `DOMContentLoaded event` occurs.

When using a script loader, `DOMContentLoaded event` might happen before all scripts are loaded, so you must **wait for all your module scripts**  and then bootstrap your application manually.

In your case, chrome probably cached your scripts so after few refreshes the `DOMContentLoaded event` happened after all scripts were loaded.

**From the docs:**

> #### Automatic Initialization
>
> Angular initializes automatically upon DOMContentLoaded event or when the angular.js script is evaluated if at that time document.readyState is set to 'complete'. At this point Angular looks for the ng-app directive which designates your application root...
>
> #### Manual Initialization
>
> If you need to have more control over the initialization process, you can use a manual bootstrapping method instead. Examples of when you'd need to do this **include using script loaders** or the need to perform an operation before Angular compiles a page.

Comment: Could you please explain what this does? I'm not familiar with this concept.

Comment: Please read the docs for more information. also see this [tutorial](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-angular-bootstrap-app-init)

Comment: Hi Ilan, I haven't had the chance to work on the application yet. I'll give it a shot after work and report back.

Comment: It's loading without issue in Chrome and Firefox now. IE is still giving me an error but it's not related to this I don't think. Something about unexpected identifier in my user service that chrome and firefox aren't completely about. But that's a different question I think. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Yup, sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually means angular can't find an object you are trying to inject into a controller or some other injectable function. After quickly looking through your code, my guess is that there is a problem with the way the files are being loaded, as you are referencing `spApp` from multiple files.

What I usually do is move separate files into their own modules, and then require other modules as needed. For example, instead of starting the userService like this:

`spApp.factory('userService', function(){`

put it into its own module

```
angular.module('spApp.services.user', [])
    .factory('userService', function(){
```

Then whenever you need to use the userService in another module, add it as a requirement. Eg:

`var spApp = angular.module('spApp', ['spApp.services.user']);`